# Can't get ngRoute to properly route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs app I'm building. I'm still new to Angular and trying to understand it.

I've put together a basic app, but I can't seem to get it to route properly. My controller code is below:

```
    var unarcoQS = angular.module('unarcoQS',['ngResource', 'ngCart', 'ngRoute', 'angular.filter']);

unarcoQS.factory('productService', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('http://example.com/api/service', {});
});

unarcoQS.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
      templateUrl:'template/home.html', 
      controller: "homeCtrl"
    })
    .when('/category',{
      // templateUrl:'template/category.html', <-- DOES NOT WORK
      template: 'Heres Johnny',                <-- WORKS
      controller: "catCtrl"
    })
    .when('/products/:PartNumber', {
      templateUrl: 'template/product.html'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);


}]);

// Controllers
unarcoQS.controller ('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'productService', 'ngCart', '$filter', function($scope, productService, ngCart) {
  console.log('Home');
}]); //end homeCtrl

unarcoQS.controller ('catCtrl', ['$scope', 'productService', 'ngCart', '$filter', function($scope, productService, ngCart) {
  ngCart.setTaxRate(7.5);
  ngCart.setShipping(2.99);

  var queryParams = {};
  productService.query(queryParams, {}, function (response) {
    $scope.products = response;
  });

  $scope.filtering = function(filter){
    $scope.catFilter = filter;
    // console.log(filter);
  };
}]); //end catCtrl
```

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <base href="/quick-ship/">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-resource/1.6.1/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/ngCart/dist/ngCart.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/pagination.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="unarcoQS">
    <div ng-include="'includes/header.html'"></div>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <footer class="fluid-container" ng-include="'includes/footer.html'"></footer>


  </body>
</html>
```

When I go to `http://myapp.com/` I see the proper template (home.html). When I navigate to `http://myapp.com/category` I end up getting a 404 if I use `templateUrl`.

If I use a string and `template` that ends up showing up.

I know I'm missing something simple, but I'm just not getting it.

Any and all help is appreciated!!

Comment: do you have `<base href="/">`in your index or main html file's head section? That is used by router to figure out the location.

Comment: I do. Sorry I forgot to post that.

Comment: when it says 404, what is the location of the request ?

Comment: My links are coming out like this: `/#%2Fcategory%2` But in my nav file I have `#/category/`

Comment: Another thing I should note is that the console.log in the `homeCtrl` is logging twice

Comment: I meant to ask what is the location of the templateURL in dev tools when you get 404? It must be requesting that html resource from a wrong location. check network tab using dev tools of your browser.

Comment: Doesn't look like it's even firing. I can provide a live URL if that would help @Sid

Comment: yup, consider giving any examples/demo/fiddles in the question itself and you will get better response.

Comment: http://ur.430designs.com/quick-ship/  I get leary sometimes on giving actual URLs. Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138687/discussion-between-sid-and-lz430).

Comment: @iz430 I've add a answer based on our investigation in chat and solution for both problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion in chat, I'm summarising our investigations and solution below:

**First issue - HTML5 Mode for client-side routing:**

> **Server side**: Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side,
>   basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your
>   application (e.g. index.html). Requiring a  tag is also
>   important for this case, as it allows AngularJS to differentiate
>   between the part of the url that is the application base and the path
>   that should be handled by the application.
>    - [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Next, after disabling the html5mode, we had to change the anchor href value for the categories to use hash before routes.

**Second issue - Nested ng-view in template:**

The next issue that we encountered was a use of nested `ng-view` directive in category template which was causing stack overflow error in the browser as Angular expect only one of this directive type in the whole app. After removing this, we managed to run your application.

Just for your information, you can use [Ui-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) if you have a need of multiples views.

You will need to look at server-side changing for URL rewriting to use AngularJS html5mode.